Getting error while trying to write to excel file sheet using python
I have an Excel file (XLSX) with multiple tabs. In tab 3, I am reading a specific cell and retrieving a value (e.g., ABC123). After reading, I close the file.
Next, I have a data frame from another source, and I apply a filter to only keep the rows that have the given value (e.g., ABC123) in a specific column. Once I have the filtered data frame, I write it to tab 5 at a specific position. To determine the position, I check if column 15, for example, has the value "20 Jul" and then take the index of that column to write the data from there.
Tab 5 has 15 columns, with the last 3 columns containing formulas. I don't modify those formulas; I only write the 12 columns from the data frame. Everything seems to be working fine until I open the file after the update, at which point I receive a message asking if I want to recover the file. I have tried changing the engine and removing it, but the issue persists.
def write_to_pcr(target_file_path, search_value, writer_df):

    # Name of Columns in PCR Report
    pcr_column_names = ['a','b','c']
    print(f'target file path is {target_file_path}')
    pcr_data_df = pd.read_excel(target_file_path,index_col=None,skiprows=1,sheet_name='MS hours',usecols=pcr_column_names)

    # Filter the DataFrame based on the 'Revenue Period' column
    filtered_df = pcr_data_df[pcr_data_df['Revenue Period'].notna()] #& pcr_data_df['Revenue Period'].dt.strftime('%y').str.contains('24')]
    #print(filtered_df['Revenue Period'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))
    #print(filtered_df.head(10))
    # Define the value to search for
    #search_value = '2024-07'
     
    pcr_data_df['Revenue Period'] = pcr_data_df['Revenue Period'].astype(str)
    
    # Find the index of the first occurrence of the given date
    #index = pcr_data_df['Revenue Period'].eq(search_value).idxmax() 
    if pcr_data_df['Revenue Period'].str.contains(search_value).any(): #search_value in filtered_df['Revenue Period'].values:
        index = filtered_df['Revenue Period'].eq(search_value).idxmax()
        
        # Adding 3 to the current index value because while reading we are skiping 3 rows from the top , since 
        # actual data starts from line 3.
        start_row_number=index+3
    else:
        index = len(filtered_df['Revenue Period'])
        start_row_number=index
        print(f'index value when not found  {index}')

   # Print the index
    print('index number is ',index+3)    

    # Write the modified DataFrame back to the same Excel file
    with pd.ExcelWriter(target_file_path, engine = "openpyxl", mode = "a",if_sheet_exists = "overlay",date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy') as writer:
        writer_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "MS hours", index = False, startrow = start_row_number, header = False)
 
    print('Data has been populated to PCR report')
    #writer.close()

The error that I am getting:


I never know there is an engine called "ExcelWriter" in pandas? I believe you want to use engine = "openpyxl".

What @Rachel said, which is the error you should have got, No Excel writer 'ExcelWriter' , not a corrupted Excel file.

Yes, I got this to try from AI but that did not work. I was using openpyxl only , that worked but it was creating that error.

You need to be more detailed; "Yes, I got this to try from AI but that did not work" Got what to try and how did it not work?  "I was using openpyxl only, that worked but it was creating that error." you mean you used other code with Openpyxl only? It worked as in, it didn't return an error but resulted in a corrupted Excel file?

What is the excel formula in your tab 5?

What if you write your writer_df dataframe to a blank excel file?  Will that excel open without error?

moken-  Initially i was using openpyxl as engine. But  that did not work. ExcelWriter is written by mistake as engine. @rachel when i am writing it in new excel file its working fine. Its not throwing error. Column have a vlookup formula

Can you click “Yes” button in your error message? Then excel would show what content needs to be removed when it “recover the file as much as it can”.

@rachel when I will click on Yes button it will recover and open file. But I want to remove this error , because business do not want this. The file that I am creating using this code will go to multiple people and it's impossible to explain everyone that why this error message is coming.

when I am running the code it gives me an warning message - "UserWarning: Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed"
